# Change Debian TTY/text terminal login OS version name

Tags: debian, kernel, login, tty

When I login to a TTY/text terminal, I get a prompt that looks something like:

```
Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid ...
login:
```

I'm running testing, and purely for aesthetic purposes, I don't want it to say `sid` here. (Who would? I don't want to be reminded of this Pixar character every time I use my computer.) Is there a way to change this without kernel hacking? Is there a way to change it at all?

Comment: search all files for `bookworm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is stored in `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net`; you can edit them to display whatever you want instead.

These files are intended to be edited by administrators, and your changes will be preserved on upgrade (but you may be asked what to do with them).

Comment: +1.  also worth noting that some getty programs support all sorts of useful escape codes.  e.g. i have `Debian GNU/Linux \n \l eth0:\4{eth0}` in /etc/issue on my cloned VMs so I don't have to grep my dhcp log for VMs with dynamic IP addresses to get an IP address to use with ssh.